# Python 2D Polynomial Fit Equivalent to IRAF's 'surfit'

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, data-fitting, astronomy

I'm working with some data trying to create a 2D polynomial fit just like IRAF's `surfit`(see [here](http://iraf.noao.edu/irafnews/dec94/dec94-S-18.html)). I have 16 data points distributed in a grid pattern (i.e. pixel values at 16 different x- and y-coordinates) that need to be fitted to produce a 1024x1024 array. I've tried a bunch of different methods, starting with things like `astropy.modeling` or `scipy.interpolate`, but nothing gives quite the right result compared to IRAF's `surfit`. I imagine it's because I'm only using 16 data points, but that's all I have! The result should look something like this:
[image]

But what I'm getting looks more like this:

[image]
or this:
[image]

If you have any suggestions for how best to accomplish this task, I would very much appreciate your input! Thank you.

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997152/python-3d-polynomial-surface-fit-order-dependent

Comment: where are the control points? also add an sample to test on ...